# Return a class from the function in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way using which I can return a `Class` as a function return type?

My sample code:

```
class Data_1{
    static int price = 1;
}

class Data_2{
    static int price = 2;
}

getData() {
    if (widget.data_name == "Data_1"){
        return Data_1;
    } else if (widget.data_name == "Data_2"){
        return Data_2;
    } 
}
    
void print_price() {print(getData.price);}
```

Using the above code getting the below error:

> The getter 'price' isn't defined for the type 'dynamic Function()'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'price', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field
> named 'names'.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: when you want to call the `getData` function you need to use its name with parenthesis `getData()`. This is why it tells you the getter is not defined for the type dynamic Function(). But this is only part of the problem. After that you will have the next exception `Class '_Type' has no instance getter 'price'. Receiver: Data_1 Tried calling: price`. This is because your getData() return type is `dynamic` and its runtime type will be `_Type` which does not know there is the `price` getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code above, to fix them:

1. We should define a `property getter` in the classes:

```
class Data_1 {
  static int _price = 1;
  get price => _price;
}

class Data_2 {
  static int _price = 2;
  get price => _price;
}
```

2. `getData()` should return an instance of the class, not the `Type`:

```
getData() {
   if (widget.data_name == "Data_1")
   {return Data_1();}   // not Data_1
   else if (widget.data_name == "Data_2") 
   {return Data_2();} } // not Data_2
}
```

3. We can now call the `getData()` function and access the `price` getter:

```
void main() {
  print(getData().price);
}
```

---

Follows the full code example:

```
class Data_1 {
  static int _price = 1;
  get price => _price;
}

class Data_2 {
  static int _price = 2;
  get price => _price;
}

getData() {
  return Data_1();
}

void main() {
  print(getData().price);
}
```